# Fully removing Flash Player from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, amd-radeon, flash-player

I'd like to remove Flash Player from Windows 8.1. I don't use IE, I uninstalled it but Flash Player remains, I only use Chrome so that would, in theory, be using only it's own PPAPI Flash.

The reason I want to do this is because regular flash messes with AMD Overdrive, it bypasses the overdrive settings and boosts the clocks to the reference design, resulting in milisecond screen corruption when it's doing it.

I tried multiple ways but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward one, if anyone has any idea I'd love to have a go at it.

Cheers

Comment: Chrome will discontinue support of PPAPI, this means, unless you enable it PPAPI Flash is disabled by default.  After you uninstall Flash from the control panel, you can disable Flash from within IE, through the [browser settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/manage-add-ons#ie=ie-11).

Comment: I don't have IE, nor does Flash show up in the Programs and Features, only in the Control Panel. Whenever I play a flash based content such as a youtube video my GPU clocks don't go up to where they're supposed to, it's a documented bug with how AMD applies UVD

Comment: You have IE, you just don't use it, or unless you specifically removed it ( which you made no mention of doing so ).  Have you remove the Flash Player Chrome plug-in?  If `Flash Player` isn't in the control panel then it isn't installed...

Comment: I did mention in the original question that I don't use it thus I uninstalled it. I also said in my last reply that Flash is not in the Programs and Features YET it is in the Control Panel. So there's no way to remove it, can't even remove the folders.

Comment: What you said was that you don't use, you didn't stay you uninstalled it, there is a slight difference.  I used Control Panel and `Add/Remove Programs and Features` interchangeably.

Comment: "I don't use IE, I uninstalled it but Flash Player remains"

Comment: I read that as you uninstalled flash player...

Answer (score 4):

#### "I'd like to remove Flash Player"

Adobe provides an uninstaller.

> - Download the uninstaller for Flash Player.
> - Exit all browsers and other programs that use Flash.
> - Run the uninstaller.
> - Verify that uninstallation is complete.

The following link provides more detailed instructions (with screenshots) and a link to the uninstaller program.

Source [Flash Player Help / Uninstall Flash Player | Windows](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html)

Comment: The page states: "These instructions are NOT applicable to Flash Player included with Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer on Windows 8 and later..."

Comment: @nicolap8 That's nice. However the question says "I only use Chrome" ...

Comment: The second part of the frase: "...or with Google Chrome on all supported operating systems."